# concatenation error in r

Tags: r, pdf, dataframe, shiny

I have a problem with my R code. I want to create an application that analyses different PDF files.
When I add more than one copy of the same PDF file it works correctly the problem appears when I upload two or more different files.

The error is :

> arguments imply differing number of rows: 117, 61

Here is my code:

```
 pdfs=as.data.frame(c(mypdf1_list(), mypdf2_list()))

  if(length(pdfs)>0){        
    doc=documents()        
    mydata=data.frame() 

    for(i in 1:length(doc) ){          
      documents<-doc[i]          
      Phrases <- pdfs[,i+(2*i)]
      Page <- pdfs[,i+((2*i)-2)]
      Line <- pdfs[,i+((2*i)-1)]          
      sparse=cbind(Phrases,Page,Line,documents)          
      mydata=rbind(mydata,sparse)          
    }
    mydata
    }
```

And here is some important details of my code:

```
 documents<-reactive({

inFile <- input$file1

c(unlist(strsplit(input$link,",")),inFile$name)
```

})

```
mypdf1_list <- reactive({
withProgress({

  if(nchar(input$link)>0){
    setProgress(message = "Downloading ...")      
    address=unlist(strsplit(input$link,","))        
    pdfs=list()        
    for(i in 1:length(address)){
      pdfs[[i]]= read_pdf(str_trim(address[i]))
    }        
    pdfs        
  }else(return(NULL))      
})    


mypdf2_list<-reactive({    
inFile <- input$file1    
if (is.null(inFile)){
  return(NULL)
}else{      
  withProgress({
    setProgress(message = "Extracting Text...")        
    lst=list()
    for(i in 1:length(inFile[,1])){
      lst[[i]] <- read_pdf(inFile[[i, 'datapath']])
    }        
    lst        
  })
})
```

I didn't figure out where could be the problem ? if it works with many copies of the same PDF file.

Comment: Likely you are `cbind`ing or `rbind`ing objects with different lengths

Comment: yes indeed im `rbind` ing two dataframes one with 117 rows and the other with  61 rows. how could this present an rbinding error ?

Comment: The answer was adding `pdff <- pdfs [[ i ]]` in the loop function. Because I was dealing with lists from the beggining. Thank you for trying to help :)